# arreglo dinámico de estructuras (uso de realloc)

Tags: array, c, manejo-de-memoria, gcc

Estoy intentando resolver un ejercicio en el que me piden crear un arreglo de estructuras usando memoria dinámica en el que se almacenarán datos obtenidos de un fichero. Inicialmente el arreglo debe tener un tamaño de 5 y tengo que usar la función realloc () para aumentar en 5 elementos nuevos cada vez que no tenga suficiente memoria. He creado la estructura, el arreglo y le he asignado una memoria dinámica pero luego no que poner como segundo argumento de la función realloc.

A continuación la definición de la estructura y del arreglo:

```
#define SIZE 80  // definición del tamaño maximo de las cadenas de caracteres
#define ARRAYSIZE 5 //definicion del tamaño maximo del arreglo de estructuras

extern int bindex;

enum modo {Auto, AdHoc, Managed, Master, Repeater, Secondary, Monitor, Unknow};
enum cifrado {on, off};

// estructura que representa los datos de una celda

struct network_st{

    unsigned int celda;
    char mac[SIZE]; 
    char essid[SIZE];
    enum modo mode;
    unsigned int canal;
    enum cifrado key;
    char calidad[5];

};

// base de datos donde se almacenarán los datos de las celdas

struct network_st * redes;
```

La asignación de memoria :

```
   redes=(struct network_st *)calloc(ARRAYSIZE, sizeof(struct network_st));
```

Y finalmente al usar realloc no se si la función está bien escrita, ni como comprobarlo:

```
redes[bindex].celda = celda;   //esta parte va dentro de un ciclo que recorre un 
strcpy(redes[bindex].mac, mac);  //fichero y va rellenado los campos de la 
strcpy(redes[bindex].essid, essid); //estructura con los datos obtenidos del fichero
redes[bindex].mode = mode;     // hasta llegar al final del mismo, cada vez 
redes[bindex].canal = canal;    // que se llene el arreglo debo aumentar la memoria  
redes[bindex].key = key;      // en la cantidad correspondiente al tamaño   
strcpy(redes[bindex].calidad, calidad); // inicial del arreglo (ARRAYSIZE)

bindex++;
contador++;

if (contador==5) {
    
    unsigned long int tam=(sizeof(*redes) + sizeof(struct network_st));
    contador =0;

    redes = (struct network_st *)realloc(redes,tam); /*esto es lo que no sé si está bien*/
}
```

He intentado imprimir el valor de tam para ver si aumenta como es de esperar pero solo aumenta despues de rellenarse los primeros 5 elementos del arreglo y no así cuando se rellena el 10mo.

Agradecería que alguien me dijera que he hecho mal con la función realloc y cómo hacerlo bien.

Saludos Yal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`realloc`](https://Por%20lo%20tanto,%20lo%20ideal%20es%20que%20en%20alguna%20variable) toma como segundo parámetro la cantidad de bytes a reservar.

Con `sizeof` obtienes el tamaño en memoria de un tipo de dato. Por lo que `sizeof(struct network_st)` devuelve el tamaño del struct. Como `redes` es un puntero a un struct `network_st`, `sizeof(*redes)` devuelve el mismo tamaño.

Entonces aquí solo estás reservando lugar suficiente para 2 elementos.

```
unsigned long int tam=(sizeof(*redes) + sizeof(struct network_st));
```

La forma en que deberías proceder es guardar el tamaño actual del arreglo en alguna variable y usarla para llamar a `realloc`.

Por ejemplo, con un arreglo de enteros:

```
int main(){
    int tamano = 5;
    int* arreglo = malloc(tamano * sizeof(int));

    // Usas el espacio disponible
    ...

    // Cuando te quedas sin reservas más
    tamano += 5;
    arreglo = realloc(arreglo, tamano * sizeof(int));

    // Ahora tienes espacio para 5 elementos más

    // No olvides liberar la memoria cuando termines
    free(arreglo);
}
```

Comment: Qué tipo variable sería aumento y qué valor tendría?

Comment: @YalAl nada, lo había planteado de otra forma pero decidí que así es más fácil. La idea era que tengas una constante `int` o una macro para cambiar fácilmente cuántos elementos adicionales puedes almacenar cada vez que llames la función `realloc`.